# PHP PDO - MySQL Query Create or Update (unique index)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hope you are well.

I have a table in a MySQL (MariaDB) database with the below schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `scheduled_immobilise` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `device` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_from` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `allow_to` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cron_id_from` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cron_id_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`account`,`device`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What I am trying to do is write a query that will either create a row (if the unique index doesn't exist), or if it already exists update it. I know you can do this by doing a select query first, but ultimately i was hoping to avoid this. Below is the SQL query I am using to create. Please note this is using PDO named placeholders..

```
INSERT INTO 
    scheduled_immobilise (
        account, 
        device, 
        allow_from, 
        allow_to, 
        active
    ) 
VALUES (
    :account, 
    :device, 
    :allow_from, 
    :allow_to,
    :active
)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Paul.

Comment: "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" for more info http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 6):

There's exactly a mysql option for this

```
INSERT INTO 
scheduled_immobilise (
    account, 
    device, 
    allow_from, 
        allow_to, 
        active
    ) 
VALUES (
    :account, 
    :device, 
    :allow_from, 
    :allow_to,
    :active
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE account = :account, device = device...etc
```

Comment: that worked nicely, i thought it was something along those lines but i was finding mixed results when i did a search. Do you know if there is any way to tell with PDO whether it has created a new record or updated?

Comment: FYI, do not expect to be able to reuse named parameters like this in all situations. My environment does not allow it and the [docs for prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) state `You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name twice in a prepared statement`

Comment: @PatrickQ i did read something about this, however I've did this many times and it works for me although im not sure if its best practice...

Answer (score 1):

a slightly more correct answer

```
INSERT INTO 
scheduled_immobilise (
    account, 
    device, 
    allow_from, 
        allow_to, 
        active
    ) 
VALUES (
    :account, 
    :device, 
    :allow_from, 
    :allow_to,
    :active
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    account = values(account), 
    device = values(device)
    ...etc
```

it will let you to use placeholders of any type, in any mode and with any driver beside PDO, while other answer will work only if emulation mode for PDO is turned on.